# How to keep grpc service definitions in sync between server and clients?

Tags: api, version-control, synchronization, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am planning to use `grpc` to build my search `API`, but I am wondering how the grpc services definitions files (e.g `.proto`) is synced between the server and the clients (assuming all use different technologies).

Also if the server had changed one of the `.proto`, how the clients will be notified to regenerate their stubs in accordance to those changes.

To summarize: how to share the definitions (`.proto`) with clients and how clients are notified if any changes to those files had occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: they aren't. All sync here is manual and usually requires a rebuild and redeploy, after you've become aware of a change, and have updated your .proto files.

Without updating, the fields and methods that you know about should at least keep working. You just won't have the new bits.

Note also: while you can *extend* schemas by adding new fields and services / methods, if you *change the meaning* of a field, or the field type, or the message types on a service: expect things to go very badly wrong.

Comment: So it is completely manual job, and can be manged only by a disciplined  workflow?

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb yes; keep in mind that on a lot of platforms, the tooling works as a compile-time step that generates code in the target language, and as you say: 
"assuming all use different technologies"; updating your Java server isn't going to do *anything* for your C++ client - the C++ client will need to be rebuilt with an updated .proto to generate the extra C++ code needed to handle it; some libraries use runtime meta-programming so could in theory adapt to .proto changes, but that still wouldn't make your code *do anything* with the additional fields, or use the new service methods

Comment: This is sad :( So it is not so flexible actually. All clients must be managed by the same process which manages the server. It is not really a distirbution...

Comment: @GinoPane that's .... frankly a really bad take; almost all APIs work this way - xml, json, etc; and that is intentional, because your code **needs to be updated** to make proper use of new data that didn't exist before; now, if you *really* want, most implementations allow you to receive and store unexpected fields, but accessing them is inherently less direct - obviously your code isn't going to just access `obj.Foo` if the code didn't know about `.Foo` when it was built. But: I'm genuinely curious about how you would, in a perfect world, want this to work. Serious question, not rhetorical.

Comment: Hm, after second thinking it looks like not an issue... If the API got breaking changes, you won't be able to use it anyway unless the client is properly updated.

Comment: @GinoPane well, that's a good reason not to make breaking changes :)